# Call dynamically a procedure with sys_refcursor as parameter

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

To simplify the problem, I`ve excluded not related code.

```
declare
v_sql_tx varchar2(4000);
cur        sys_refcursor;
begin
    v_sql_tx := 'procedure(' || cur || ')';
    execute immediate v_sql_tx;
end;
```

This will result into error `PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to '||'`.

Is there a way to have interpolated cursor as parameter ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have over-simplified the question and actually do have a legitimate reason to use dynamic SQL - e.g. dynamic procedure name - then you can use a bind variable for the argument and then bind the cursor in the `execute immediate` call. Your procedure call will need to be in an anonymous block anyway though:

```
declare
v_sql_tx varchar2(4000);
cur        sys_refcursor;
begin
    v_sql_tx := 'begin procedure(:cur); end;';
    execute immediate v_sql_tx using cur;
end;
```

But use a static call if you can, as @Littlefoot showed.

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=5f111ce9be688c5dc0bd930bb7809c40) showing both.

Comment: Yes, the schema name is dynamic

Answer (score 1):

If you didn't oversimplify it, then you don't need dynamic SQL.

```
declare
  cur sys_refcursor;
begin
  procedure(cur);        --> presuming that "procedure" actually represents some procedure name
end;
```

Comment: It seems I oversimplified, I need to have it interpolated, as I have the schema name dynamic.